# MySQL Update Issue - NULL fields get updated, but not fields already containing data

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I am struggling with a MySQL query. Here's the problem:

```
SELECT * from sf_forecasts WHERE contentid='1234' AND fulldate='2012-12-13'
```

There is one record in my table that matches this criteria, and this query finds it with no difficulty. However, when I move to update it using this query...

```
UPDATE sf_forecasts
SET listingTitle ='Some Snow Resort', location ='49.23, -115.22'
WHERE contentid='1234' AND fulldate='2012-12-13'
```

...I always get a notice of "0 rows affected." Strangely, the query is actually updating the record, but it's only touching fields that are NULL. If my example record has a 'location' value of NULL, the query will update the data, but if it already contains a non-NULL value, the query will not change it, even though the query clearly contains new information.

What gives?

P.S. I am using a PRIMARY key of contentid+fulldate (b-tree, unique) if this matters.

P.S.S. Here is the 'SHOW CREATE TABLE sf_forecasts' results as requested below:

```
sf_forecasts    CREATE TABLE `sf_forecasts` (
`contentid` int(11) NOT NULL,
`fulldate` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`listingTitle` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`location` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`dayofmonth` smallint(2) NOT NULL,
`dayofweek` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`minTempF` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
`maxTempF` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
`minTempC` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
`maxTempC` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
`skyCondition` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`precip` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`snowPotential` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`wind` varchar(100) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`minTempF_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`maxTempF_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`minTempC_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`maxTempC_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`baseH_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`baseL_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`topH_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`topL_custom` smallint(4) DEFAULT NULL,
`skyCondition_custom` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`precip_custom` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`snowPotential_custom` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`wind_custom` varchar(200) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`icon` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`icon_custom` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`shortrange_custom` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`longrange_custom` varchar(5000) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`scCode` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`scUpdate` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`lastUpdate` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`skys` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`contentid`,`fulldate`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci
```

Comment: Can you post `SHOW CREATE TABLE sf_forecasts` output please?

Comment: Certainly. I will add it to the original posting.

Comment: @inhan, why have you removed original `location` value with your edit? It is important to have it as it were before. Plus, variables in single quotes are not expanded!

Comment: I will change that back. That's not an accurate view of what actually shows up in the 'location' variable anyway.

Comment: @RomanNewaza it was already removed (by an edit by OP) at the time of my editing. All I did was to break the 2nd query into multiple lines. I didn't touch anything in the script or text.

Comment: It's been fixed. That was me trying to make the post shorter and more readable, but the contents of the field were not accurate when they reflected ='$latlong' -- my bad.

Comment: @Aboutimage why is everything `VARCHAR`? there are numerous other datatypes much convenient for majority of the columns.

Comment: @inhan, you're surely correct on that, but does it have any impact on the original question / issue? The reason they are this way is because the database in question has been used for a long time (a decade almost) in its present form, and I was not sure whether I should change formats and potentially insert problems for people whose code was expecting data in VARCHAR format. I'm not experienced enough with MySQL to know what I can safely change :)

Comment: Your location is `varchar(10)` and you are trying to insert `14` characters?

Comment: Doh! You wanna change that note to an answer, @rs? I just updated the table format and like magic, it took the update. I feel like an idiot for not seeing that...

Comment: @Aboutimage i posted my comment as answer below

Comment: @Aboutimage I strongly recommend updating the table structure for performance. Don't be afraid, just go step by step (aka. column by column) and create a query to analyze the structure of values for that column. And if there's no problem, just update the datatype and necessary scripts.

Comment: If you had used [strict mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/innodb/1.1/en/glossary.html#glos_strict_mode) this wouldn't have happened :)

Comment: @inhan, thanks, I will definitely look into that.

Comment: @Jack is it an option for `MyISAM` engine also?

Comment: @inhan Hmm I'm afraid not :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is with difference in datatype length defined and length of data being updated

Your location is `varchar(10)` and you are trying to insert `14 characters`

Comment: Thanks so much! Nice to have fresh eyes able to see the forest thru the trees!

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if there are errors after query execution:

```
SHOW ERRORS;

SHOW WARNINGS;
```